# Regex between quotes

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have to parse as part of a project a playlist file:

The layout looks like this:

```
{
         "info" : "",
         "time" : "05:00",
         "url_stream" : "http://loopstream01.apa.at/?channel=oe1&id=20120726_0500_1_2_nachrichten_XXX_w_",
         "day_label" : "26.07.2012",
         "short_title" : "Nachrichten",
         "url_detail" : "",
         "url_json" : "/programm/308178/konsole",
         "parts" : [],
         "tag" : "",
         "id" : "308178",
         "title" : "Nachrichten",
         "url_playlist" : "/programm/308178/playlist"
      },........... and so on
```

now i want to get the values of the "properties". I tried this one

```
"info" : "(?<info>(([^"]*)))", ....
```

but it is buggy because the it is possible that there is something like this:

"info" : "Hello "World" this was a test",

you see that "World" is also in "" and so it gets buggy.
Does anyone has a good and clean solution for me?

Comment: Use a JSON parser, please. I think C# has this feature built-in.

Comment: This looks like JSON. Have you considered a JSON parser for C# instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two similar pages on internet. They can be parsed using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) as below:

```
using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
    string url = "http://derruki.dyndns.org/oe1rip/json-list-source.php";
    string json = wc.DownloadString(url);

    dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
    foreach(var item in dynObj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("INFO:{0}\nTITLE:{1}\nURL:{2}\n\n",
            item.info, item.short_title, item.url_stream);
    }
}
```

For `http://oe1.orf.at/programm/konsole/tag/20120726` you should change for loop as

```
foreach(var item in dynObj.list)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `JavaScriptSerializer` class, documented by Microsoft [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx), to deserialize the JSON. That will be much easier than RegEx.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
(?<=[\n\r])[^\S\n\r]*"info"[^\S\n\r]*:[^\S\n\r]*"(?<info>.*?)",?[^\S\n\r]*(?=[\n\r])
```